# What is the best way to store a dynamic webpage as an object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a php application with MySQL for database.

I want to create a site builder. The idea is to use ajax for loading and storing the dynamic page content. The user will be able to modify the site (create and edit pages, navigation menus, etc.) while viewing the front-end. The changes will be presented in real time, and then committed once saved.

I'm not sure what would be the best method for manipulating and storing the dynamic page content.

Should I just change the DOM, and then save its current state somehow? Or, would it be better to use an object for storing the page's content and structure? Would it be better to store the pages in SQL, or file?

***EDIT***
So, what I decided on, if it helps anyone (and thanks to all who responded!):

I have created jQuery functions which allow the user to manipulate the DOM simply by clicking an element on the page, and then adding content to a new element (so for example I have a text and image insert tool). I'm using a handler object to track changes, which are then applied to the DOM once the user clicks update button.

Once the user saves the page, I am using ajax to save a portion of the DOM to a MySQL database.

Then I have a pagebuilder function created which calls my custom theme's header, pulls the html from the database, and then calls the theme's footer.

So far this is working very well. The pagebuilder takes care of constructing the page by using the url's `?page=x` reference. This still allows my core app and theme system to control each page's header and footer, while still allowing for an easy way to edit, save and retrieve the content, all using ajax.

Comment: take a look at how [nuggetz](http://www.nuggetz.co.uk/) does it. It is pretty simple and easy to understand. But that is only one way to "skin the cat"

Comment: Thank you. I'll surely look at nuggetz. Seems to be very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have modified it and use it in production for some clients who are completely impressed by the usability and features it has. So simple yet so elegant. It's under the [BSD license](http://www.linfo.org/bsdlicense.html) so have at looking at the source and modifying it as needed.

Comment: If you're not concerned about adding version control then just send the whole page (via an ajax call) to a server-side script that saves it as html.  No need for a database for simple sites.

Comment: Thanks, @Archer. Normally these sites will only have a dozen pages, but what if we have a need for thousands of pages? Is there any benefit at that point to store in database rather than html files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience with Magento and your dynamic things, i think it'll better to save the dynamic content on database, but saving things like:

"Home"
"3 columns"
"Input - Text"
...

And when you get it back, you use the "directions" saved on database, to build your dynamic website.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion definitely helped me narrow down the final decision to store the content in database. I create a page-builder.php function which basically acts as the "directions".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is a matter of architecture here. Storing in a Database will provide you better performance retrieving and storing long data streams, and will probably a better data organization along the way.

The question is -how can you store a Web site into a Database efficiently?-

Has a partner say before there are many ways of skin the cat. How complex do you want to go? are you going to store single pages? images? tables? full websites? will your users be able to store raw/other data too?

You see?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent questions, which I have considered. Originally I wanted to store everything the page could possibly contain, but now I believe I'm going to create a method of editing pre-determined regions. I'd +1 your answer, but don't have the rep, so here's a **thank you**!